# permanent notification does not show

Tags: android, notifications

I submitted my app at the end of 2017 in the play store and it worked.
Then it was built in Eclipse.

Now I run it in Android Studio and the same code doesn't show any notification.
It is a permanent notification which is present after I call the app's `finish()` method. (why I do this: see at the bottom if you want to know).

So I looked at all the examples and NONE of the work. No single notification is shown.

So I start an activity and in the activity I show the notification. Then I call `finish()`.

This is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                intent, 0);

        CharSequence connectedPart = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

        String melding = "";

        melding = getResources().getString(R.string.screentimeoutsetto) + " "  + newTimeString + ".";
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(connectedPart)
                .setTicker(connectedPart)
                .setContentText(melding)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        notificationManager.notify(2, notification);
```

dependencies:

```
dependencies{
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0"
}
```

Why I do this:
My app does 1 thing: toggle the screentimeout. So when you start it it sets the screentimeout to 30 minutes (starts, sets a notification, then `finish()`). Start again, it removes the notification and restore the original value for the screen timeout.

Comment: You haven't set a notification channel for your notification, [which is required on later Android APIs](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels). What API level are you testing on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Android Oreo, all notifications require a notification channel, otherwise the notification wont post and an error will appear in your logcat. Here's an example of how you can do it, lifted from one of my apps:

```
private static void createNotificationChannel(Context ctx) {
    if(SDK_INT < O) return;

    final NotificationManager mgr = ctx.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    if(mgr == null) return;

    final String name = ctx.getString(R.string.channel_name);
    if(mgr.getNotificationChannel(name) == null) {
        final NotificationChannel channel =
                new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        mgr.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}

//Usage...
createNotificationChannel(context);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_white_24dp);
//etc...
manager.notify(id, builder.build());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought I've tried this already, but probably not in this form. Hours of endless trying are over!

Comment: Did you turn off all your logcat filters? Sometimes I have more luck using logcat from the command line, `adb logcat -b all -v color`

Comment: I think I did. I will recheck.

Answer (score 1):

Now from Android 8.0 and onward you need to create notification channel before showing notifications. Here is the Docs [link](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels